# Locate file in from the file system root knowing sub-folder

Tags: php

I made this code below to find the path of file in my locat system, I would like to change this code to locate my-file and return its absolute path knowing that the only thing we remember about this file is that it is saved in a sub-folder /tmp/documents:

- /tmp/documents can contain nested sub-folders and my-file can belong to any one of them.
- If my-file cannot be found then your program should return NULL
  Example:
  locateFile() returns /tmp/documents/a/b/c/my-file if my-file  is found into the folder /tmp/documents/a/b/c.

  ```
   <?php

  function locatefile(){
   $flags = 0;
   $pattern = 'my-file';
   $files = glob($pattern, $flags);
   foreach (glob(dirname($pattern) . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR |  GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) 
      {
   $files = array_merge($files, locatefile($dir . '/'  .basename($pattern), $flags));          

  }
  return $files;
   }
  // code test do not change it
  $folder = '/tmp/documents/' . rand() . '/' . rand();
  mkdir($folder, 0700, true);
  touch($folder . '/my-file');
  echo "EXAMPLE:$folder/my-file\n";
  echo "RESULT:" . locatefile();
  ```

Comment: If linux or mac then `exec` to `find /tmp/documents/ -name "my-file"`

Comment: I want to do it with a php code